Tree View Component Multilevel Data Edit (React, Typescript)
I'm trying to create a TreeView component with React and Typescript.
The initial treedata is only root level like:
"data": {
  "name": "root",
  "children": []
}

When click the expand icon on TreeView then send a request to the backend to get the children that belong to this treeData, And the treedata may have multi-level.
I tried to do it with MUI but failed, I can't update the treedata children at a deep level.
How to update the deep level treedata children[] and update UI currently.
The current method is to use an array treedata[] to store all entries as a list, and filter that treedata[].parent like this. But the total entries have over ten thousand data. if filter treedata[] every time will make the loading time too long.
treedata.filter((x) => x.parent === targetParentName{
 return <treeitem data={x}>
})
"data": {
  "name": "root",
  "parent": "parentTreeDataName",
  "children": []
}

Can anyone give a suggestion or do you know which UI library can handle it? I would the loading time shorter.
Thank you !!!
The total treedata may have over ten thousand data.
"data": {
  "name": "root",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "A", 
      "children": [
          {
            "name": "AA",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "AB",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
    },
    {
      "name": "B",
      "children": [
          {
            "name": "BA",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "BB",
            "children": [
                {
                  "name": "BBA",
                  "children": []
                },
                {
                  "name": "BBB",
                  "children": []
                }
              ]
          }
        ]
    },
    {
      "name": "C",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}


There is a programming concept/algorithm called and "index". You need to "index" your data by a property that uniquely defines it. In you case this is the "name" property. So, once you get the data, you should do a one-time restructuring of the data into a format that uses the "index' concept. I recommend using a Map object, in this case Map<string,SomeCustomTreeNodeType> where the key of the map is formed by the "name" property. You can recursively apply these concepts if you need indexing at lower levels of the tree. You may need to study about this, and experiment with different options.
Try to use this concept to help create your component, and post a separate question if you run into issues.
